# How to convert pixel distances in meters distances

Tags: python, image-processing, template-matching

I'm working on cloud displacement, the main idea is to use template matching to determine the movement of the template from (x0, y0) at image t0 to (x1, y1) at image at tn+1. If I apply to those coordinates, then the euclidean distance result is given in pixels, but the result must be in meters.

Using images from GOES-16 from channel 13, the datasheet says that the spatial spacing is 2 km.
So, to convert the pixel distance only I have to mulply that value for the spatial distance? or how do I do to achieve it?

Comment: Yes, multiply the distance in pixels by the size of a pixel to get the physical distance. The 2 km is the size of a pixel.

Answer (score 0):

What resolution are you working with? This typically should be in DPI(Dots per inches), if you divide your pixels dimension by the resolution, you should have the resultant dimensions in inches. Then you can convert the inches value to kilometres by dividing by 254000.
For example a 1440 X 576 pixel image with a resolution of 72DPI should be measure 20inches X 8 inches.
(https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.shutterstock.com/blog/inches-to-pixels-resize-image-quality/amp)

Comment: The original image have 2500 of width and 1667 of height, GOES documentation says 2 km of spatial resolution

Comment: Some images have a pixel size specified with DPI, but many other images don’t. Assuming satellite imagery is measured in inches is rather absurd, to be honest. 0.000001 DPI?

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand